# 'ICollection<Table1>' does not contain a definition for Table2

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Reason of this error is i have changed Table2 interface like "public ICollection Country { get; set; }" before its was not a ICollection.Reason for change this is i couldn't get table2 values in a view

and no accessible extension method 'Table2' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection

```
 entity.HasOne(d => d.Table1)
                    .WithMany(p => p.**Table2**)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.Table1ID)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Table2_Table1");
            });
```

I have error in Table2 in above code
This error is occured in dbcontext.cs

table1 Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace website.Models
{
    public partial class Table1
    {
        public Table1()
           
        {
           Table2 = new HashSet<Table2>();

        }

       
      
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Update { get; set; }
        public string Edit { get; set; }

        public Table Table { get; set; }
        public ICollection< Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

Table2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace website.Models
{
    public partial class Table2
    {
        public Table2()
        {
            Table3 = new List<Table3>();
           
        }

            
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string MotherName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int? QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string SecurityAnswer { get; set; }
  

        public ICollection<Table3> Table3 { get; set; }
        public table1 table1 { get; set; }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `.Include(i => i.Table2)`?

Comment: yes .. `var data = db.Table.Include(x => x.Table2)` this is my code

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how to fix this error ? @MohammadBarbast

Comment: Share your Entity Models (Table1 ,Table2) in your question, please.

Comment: Please check ,I don't know what's the exact error  @MohammadBarbast

Comment: Share Table2, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two tables, one filled with `Table1Elements` and one filled with `Table2Elements`.

There seems to be a one-to-many relation between Table1 and Table2: every `Table1Element` has zero or more `Table2Elements`, and every `Table2Element` belongs to exactly one `Table1Element`, namely the one that the foreignkey `Table2Element.Table1ElementId` refers to.

If you would have followed the [entity framework conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), then this description would have been better readable. Next time consider to stick to using nouns to refer to tables and properties, and use plural nouns when referring to collections, and singular nouns when referring to single elements.

*I tried to continue typing my answer using Table1 / Table1Element and Table2 / Table2Element, but this became quite unreadable. Hence I give you the answer using the one-to-many between Schools and Students: every School has zero or more Students, every Student studies at exactly one School, the School that the foreign key refers to.*

If you prefer Table1 and Table2: please replace Schools with Table1 and Students with Table2.

You will have classes similar as the following:

```
class School
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every School has zero or more Students (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
}

class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Student studies at exactly one School, using foreign key
    public int SchoolId {get; set;}
    public virtual School School {get; set;}
}
```

This is enough for entity framework code first to detect your relationship and create the tables for you. It also detects your primary keys and the foreign keys.

> In entity framework the non-virtual properties refer to the columns of the tables, the virtual properties refer to the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

The foreign key is an actual column in the table, hence it is non-virtual. School is not a column in the Student table, a School is related to this Student. Hence School is virtual.

If you want to specify the one-to-many relation in your `DbContext.OnModelCreating`, you can use:

Starting from Schools:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<SChool>()
    .HasMany(school => school.Students)           // Is this your problem?
    .WithOne(student => student.School)
    .HasForeignKey(student => student.SchoolId);
```

In words: Every `School` in the table of Schools, has zero or more `Students`, which can be referred to using property `School.Students`.

Every `Student` attends exactly one `School`. This `School` can be accessed via `Student.School`. The foreign key of this is in `Student.SchoolId`.